# Samsung fingerprint reader in mvc project

Tags: model-view-controller

is there a way to get my mvc system to prompt the user for fingerprint authentication but not with an external device?

I want my system to be able to use the built in mobile finger print reader on android devices so that when they make a request on their phone, they will be asked for their fingerprint and they can just scan it from their phone.